# When i use a for loop with an array it doesn't work and uses the number of items instead of going item by item

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop

Basically in the last `for` loop the k variable uses the number of items in the list and then I have a false and unique answer rather than multiple answers I want to do some sort of n roots of a complex number (if my question isn't clear sorry i'm not a native english speaker I'll do my best to make it clearer)

```
from math import *
deg = int(input("entrez le degré:"))
re = int(input("le réel:"))
im = int(input("l'imaginaire:"))
counter = 0
while counter < deg:
    counter = counter + 1
    kkk = []
    kkk.append(counter)
r = sqrt(pow(re,2)+pow(im,2))
if im != 0:
    teton = round(pi/radians(degrees(acos(re/r))),1)
else:
    teton = round(pi/radians(degrees(acos(im/r))),1)
if round(r) != r:
    r = "sqrt(",(pow(re,2)+pow(im,2)),")"
else:
   r = r
teta  = "pi/%s" %teton
print("z = ",r,"e^i",teta,)
for k in kkk:
    if re != 0 or im != 0:
        print(r,"e^i*2*",teta,"*",k,"pi")
    else:
        print(r,"^1/",deg,"e^i(",teta,"/",deg," +(2",k,"pi)/",deg)
    print(k)
```

Comment: Observation: `while counter < deg:`: at the end of it `kkk` will only have one element: `deg`. I highly doubt that's intended (you should place `kkk = []` before the loop). Also: assuming that its purpose is only to generate that list: it could be replaced by: `kkk = list(range(1, deg + 1))` (as your code is now the list should start with 1 and end with `deg`).

Comment: that's my problem actually idk why it appends only one element and on top of that it's deg i was hoping it'll be like
    [0,1,2...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, you are saying that for loop is not iterating over all the items in the list kkk.

if you check your code the list kkk always have only one item as you are initializing and appending item in same loop.
please move below statement out of the first loop.

```
 kkk = []
```

like below.

```
from math import *
deg = int(input("entrez le degré:"))
re = int(input("le réel:"))
im = int(input("l'imaginaire:"))
counter = 0
kkk = []
while counter < deg:
    counter = counter + 1


    kkk.append(counter)
r = sqrt(pow(re,2)+pow(im,2))
if im != 0:
    teton = round(pi/radians(degrees(acos(re/r))),1)
else:
    teton = round(pi/radians(degrees(acos(im/r))),1)
if round(r) != r:
    r = "sqrt(",(pow(re,2)+pow(im,2)),")"
else:
   r = r
teta  = "pi/%s" %teton
print("z = ",r,"e^i",teta,)

for k in kkk:
    if re != 0 or im != 0:
        print(r,"e^i*2*",teta,"*",k,"pi")
    else:
        print(r,"^1/",deg,"e^i(",teta,"/",deg," +(2",k,"pi)/",deg)
    print(k)
```

Comment: thanks a lot i didn't think about it how stupid i am i was lost for an hour for something that simple :/ have a nice day

Comment: by the way did you check @CristiFati 's comment. I also agree that you can just use range instead of initializing a list for "for" loop.